# Can you have dependency injection in a .css file?

Tags: css, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, razor-pages, code-injection

I have a c# .NET 6 app. Some of the web pages (razor pages) of the app are using dependency injection, injecting configuration into the razor pages (the .cshtml files) so that some config elements can be displayed in the UI.

My question is, is it possible to inject configuration in a similar way to a .css file? Is it possible to have something similar to this in a .css file:

```
/**mycssfile.css**/
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration

.mystyle {
 background-image: Configuration.image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the `@import` keyword, if you are just looking to bring in rules from other style sheets.

> The @import CSS at-rule is used to import style rules from other valid stylesheets. An @import rule must be defined at the top of stylesheet, before any other at-rule (except @charset and @layer) and style declaration, else it will be ignored.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import

However, if you are trying to bring in values, strings, or any other kind of data from C# (which you appear to want in your example), you’re going to have to dynamically build the CSS file content in an endpoint on your server (where you have access to the C# values), then send that down to the browser where it acts like just another style sheet.

The issue is, once the browser parses CSS, it does not have access to your server’s code, because it’s already been downloaded.

Although, the functionality I just described may already be available to use as a built-in feature of the .NET framework, otherwise, you’ll have to code it yourself in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

CSS files are plain text and are not processed by ASP.NET Core. Consequently, it is not possible to execute server-side code within them. However, you can easily use a Razor page to generate your CSS file, which will support DI etc (although you likely lose any CSS support offered by your IDE).

Here's the PageModel for an example. Note that the `ContentType` for the `Response` has been altered:

```
public class CssModel : PageModel
{
    public string TextColor => "green";
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Response.ContentType= "text/css; charset=utf-8";
    }
}
```

Here's the *.cshtml* file content. The *Layout* has been set to null:

```
@page
@model WebApplication3.Pages.CssModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
body{
    font-family:consolas;
    color: @Model.TextColor;
}
```

Here's an example of a page that uses the generated CSS. Note here that the script is being output in a [section](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/files/layout#sections):

```
@page
@model CssTestModel
@{
}
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p>This page tests Razor generated CSS</p>

@section styles{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css" />
}
```

And here's the layout page's `head` section that includes the necessary `RenderSection` call:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    @RenderSection("styles", false)
</head>
```